# (laravel) getting the correct product in the value tag

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart

so, what I want is that I get the correct item in my shopping cart.
What I want to know is what do I write in this value tag.

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
```

What is the result I want, example:
product with id 1 = cake. If I click on product 1 it will appear in the shooping cart.

```
 <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="#">

<!-- Specify a PayPal Shopping Cart Add to Cart button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<table id="myTable">
<tr class="header">
    <th>console</th>
    <th>release date</th>
    <th>company</th>
    <th>price</th>
</tr>
@foreach($results as $result)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{$result->name}}
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$result->releasedate}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$result->company}}
        </td>
        <td>
            € {{$result->price}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Display the payment button. -->
            <input type="image" name="submit"
                   src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif"
                   alt="Add to Cart">
            <img alt="" width="1" height="1"
                 src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

ps I don't know if this is important, but I say it anyway, all the products are located in a database.

EDIT

```
 public function update($console, Request $request)
{
    $consoles = consoles::find($console);
    $consoles->name = $request->name;
    $consoles->releasedate = $request->releasedate;
    $consoles->company = $request->company;
    $consoles->price = $request->price;
    $consoles->save();
    return redirect('/console');
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $consoles = new consoles();
    $consoles->name = input::get('name');
    $consoles->releasedate = input::get('releasedate');
    $consoles->company = input::get('company');
    $consoles->price = input::get('price');
    $consoles->created_at = null;
    $consoles->updated_at = null;
    $consoles->save();

    return redirect('console');
}
```

EDIT 2

I just tested

```
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{ $result->name }}">
```

this is what I got

I went to my first product and clicked on the button add to chart

when I looked in the shopping cart I saw that the last item had been added to the cart

Comment: `value="{{ $result->id }}"`  ? I don't really understand what you want to do but maybe it's this

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine oke {{ $result->id }} only shows the id of the product i want to see the name, {{ $result->name }} only give me the last product in my database

Comment: It should be `{{ $result->name }}`. Have you try to var_dump  $results and how did you get this variable ? I think it's more a problem in how you get and foreach it because `{{ $result->name }}` should return the current element name

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine var_dump($results) show all the products in the database and the variable $results is form my controller               public function index()
    {
        $results = consoles::all();
        return view('console.console', compact('results'));
    }

Comment: So if $results show all the product and in your foreach you use `{{$result->name}}` who should return the correct name you can use it for set the value with `{{ $result->name }}`. If this not work , show me more code. I need to see your request in your controller and what you try when you said with `$request->name`

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine So what It does is when I press add to cart it adds the last product in the database I will also edit my post with store and update form my controller

Comment: This is not the code I want to see, btw how can i know what is this console thing ? Why use the input helper in store method ? Do you pass the parameter in get ? You should use the request object here like you do in your update method. 
At the beginning you just want to pass the name in a input value and know your speaking about your store and update methode so I don't understand your problem

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine oke what is the code you want to see? I have controller, model, migrations. also the console is just the veriable. the problem is that I don't get to see the right product when I add a product to the cart. p.s if you want I coul upload my entire project.

Comment: If I undertsand you just want `<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="">` and passing the name of the product in the value. So `{{ $result->name }}` should do it, you say you try this but doesn't work so I want to see the code where you try.  After this you say you want to add it on the databse, in this case you should use the id instead of the name. So explain clearly what do you want and what is your problem. Adding the product on the db or have the name in the value of the hidden input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my own problem, it was somthing really stupid.